# Get a Short from a UUID

Tags: java

My objects have a field of type "id":UUID.
In my program, however, I also need a second ID for each object, which is displayed with shorts.
I would prefer to derive / calculate this from the actual ID

Since a short only consists of two bytes, it is clear that I cannot just type-cast, but there may be a possibility to calculate a more or less unique short variable from the UUID-ID.

Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: There is no way to map a 128 bit UUID into a unique 16 bit short without collisions (Having some 128bit values refer to the same 16 bit values). That's just mathematically impossible.

Comment: Sure, but it may be a possible to cut of the first two bytes or maxbe calculating some kind of 2 byte long hashsum of it. Even its possbile that the resulting values are not 100% unique, it maybe uniqe enought for my case

Comment: A UUID can – in theory – represent 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 distinct values. A short can only represent 65536 values. 65k is a really low number: if you generate one new value per second, in less than a day would have exhausted all possible values.

Answer (score 3):

There are some options and things to consider.

An [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) consists of [128 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit_computing). When you want represent it a smaller version (short = 16-bit) there is always a higher risk of collision!

There are two ways that I can think of to get a shorter "representation" or connection to your UUID:

1. Direct Mapping to a number (I suggest using this)

Map the UUID to a short number (ranges from -32,768 to 32,767). Keep in mind you are limited in the amount using short. Just increment the number and map UUID and short ID.

Example:

```
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 -> 1
e7511ef3-849e-4cee-b194-8f238ca88ce2 -> 2
```

If you **really** want to derive the second ID consider hashing:

2. Hashing

Hashfunctions map data to fixed-size values. So you can use a Hashfunction to reduce the size. For example, a [Pearson Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing) is a 8 bit hash function or [Fletcher-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum) is a 16 bit hash function.

Additionally, UUIDs have a static part maybe you can ignore it and find a mapping function yourself.